# Dynamically change the page title to a textbox in IE11

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, internet-explorer-11, bho

How to change the page title dynamically in IE11?

The extension is highlighted.when click the extension it will take the page title and XML path and send it to the server using a ajax call.The page title is shown with the extension icon in a text box.

The thing is if i am changing the title it should dynamically reflect in the server also.but its not working to me , how can i do that?

can any one help me to do that?

[[image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.title = "title";` for javascript. Use the ajax request to send the changed title along with the XPath as soon as the changes occure.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this on Javascript:

```
 document.title = "Your new title";
```

But is no good for SEO